# U.S.A. with 51 states?

Tags: alternate-history

In a slightly different timeline, the [flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flag_of_the_United_States#Historical_progression_of_designs) is seen to have 51 stars.

What are plausible (and interesting) candidates for another state?

I could just [pick a territory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puerto_Rico#Referendums_on_statehood_or_independence)<sup>※</sup> and imply that it became a state at some point.  But I’d like an *interesting* backstory, with some turning point that happened differently there, or some reason different from the cases of [AK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alaska) or [HI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hawaii#Political_changes_of_1954_%E2%80%93_the_State_of_Hawaii_(1959%E2%80%93present)).

The story takes place in the 2030’s with some flashbacks to our present time.

---

※ PR is too obvious unless you have a good story behind it other than “it went through”.

Comment: Sorry, too broad question and more about story line than worldbuilding.

Comment: "interesting" is a totally subjective feeling...

Comment: @Guran Now that's amazing! How can it be "more about story line than worldbuilding" when there's not a hint of story in the question?

Comment: @a4android I interpreted the question as a search for a story behind state 51 rather than a question about what that state might be.

Comment: Both Australia and the United Kingdom often "joke" about becoming the 51st State of the USA. Since Australia already has six states and two territories, it could become the 51st through to 59th states. There were suggestions Quebec might join the USA back when there was strong secessionist movement in the late 20th century.

Comment: @Guran It's easy to do something like that, but the question asks for plausible (and interesting) candidates. The OP seems to be looking possible states. Presumably the OP will have to work the story of how that happens. American geography isn't my strong suit. You probably know much more than I do. Have fun!

Comment: Since I can't answer because of hold, consider that you can make anyplace on N. American continent both plausible and interesting in innumerable ways. One: other time line there's a plate division that runs southerly and somewhat parallel to thy

Comment: to the American-Mexican border. It began very frequent and continual earthquake activity such that an ever expanding massive gorge emerged between the two nations for most of the border a though it doesn't reach the ocean on either side. Bridges of the past continually failed so USA ended up acquiring a 51st state because it made sense in many ways.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question and here's why: While JD may need to clarify the grammar a bit to prove me right, I did NOT interpret the question as asking for storybuilding or non-factual information that would justify the answers. In fact, providing actual data to justify why any location on earth would be a good candidate for the 51st state is exactly what a good fishing-for-ideas question should be (vs. just asking for a list of candidates, which would be a POB question).  @L.Dutch, I understand your comment about "interesting," but could you weigh in with more insight as to your VTC?

Comment: @JBH, allowing another state to the union is way beyond just "numbers". It's mainly a political discussion, and as such strongly opinion based.

Comment: I'd argue more 'geopolitical' than 'political' - there's potential here for a solid answer regarding countries with 51st state potential, though I suspect History.se might have the better skillset to answer this one

Comment: If you want to make it interesting and creative, perhaps instead of adding territory (for which there are several well-established and hence boring candidates like Guam, Puerto Rico or England), consider splitting a state into two because of major internal issues. People are easily polarized these days, creating a back story would be fun and easy

Comment: @Raditz_35, but I would argue that subdividing states is even more boring.  99% of the time it's a desire to separate economically and a perceived difference in culture is merely the excuse, while annexing something outside current borders brings with it new resources, an entirely new culture, new tactical and strategic possibilities, etc.  Frankly, our military would likely give their collective left eye to annex the island containing Sevastopol or Kyrgystan.

Comment: @JBH Tbo I don't understand your concern. If it was your question, it would be entirely up to you to make it the 1% that you personally find interesting (I don't know where you get 99% from btw, did it happen that often?). I've noted that this would be basically story-based. I'm offering him an alternative to think about. You can make anything boring if you choose a boring story, e.g. the US makes China their 51st state because of a technicality that changes nothing.

Comment: @Raditz_35, I apologize for offending you.  I was merely responding to your statement, "If you want to make it interesting and creative...."  But, as you suggest, we all focus on the 1% that makes it interesting to ourselves.

Comment: this doesn't seem to story based, abit broad certainly (it would be good to know if you are talking about how far in the future or past you are saying) but it shouldn't be closed.

Answer (score 6):

Personally, I don't think you can go past [Panama](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panama#History). There is some pretty strong evidence that Theodore Roosevelt had a [major hand to play](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_Panama_from_Colombia#Separation) in the separation of Panama from Colombia, but there is also a compelling argument to state that the USA at the time had no interest in an  expanding colonial presence at the time. They (quite frankly) had bigger fish to fry on the domestic stage including industrial monopolies, coal strikes and a wide gap between the wealthy and the impoverished.

That said; the Panama Canal was important to US trade interests, and there is precedent for the USA purchasing land of strategic value and forming states. Both Louisiana and Alaska were purchased (from the French and Russians respectively) so if the US at the turn of the twentieth century had been prosperous enough to do so, there is a case that Roosevelt may have simply offered to *buy* Panama off Colombia.

Whether they would have been willing to sell is a matter for the ages, but there was certainly discontent on both sides (Panama and Colombia) with the extant situation at the time. I don't know enough global history to comment on what proportion of that discontent was directly attributable to the USA's involvement in politics within the region, but let's for a moment assume that Colombia didn't actually want Panama, and the USA was in a position to purchase it outright.

You'd have your 51st state.

In hindsight, this could have led to other strategic benefits in South America after the need for trade ships going through the canal started to dwindle and the purchase could have been a very useful strategic decision by Roosevelt if he had the money to do it (which as I understand it he simply didn't). Still, it would be one of those areas that would be sufficiently large that could be called a state in its own right and the US would have strong reasons through most of the 20th century to maintain it as such.

Of course, this is speculative, and doesn't account for cultural integration issues that may have also arisen from such a purchase. That said, Alaska is an interesting mix of both Russian and US cultures, something similar may well have developed in Panama.

Comment: "Alaska is an interesting mix of both Russian and US cultures" is it really? if it is that seems strange to me, because I didn't think Russia had ever bothered to settle Alaska when they had it & a quick Google search prompted by those doubts took me to Wikipedia who tell me that Russian descendants are one of the least populous ethnic demographics in Alaska, being last on their list at 14th place & accounting for just 1.4% of Alaska's population (Germans make up 18.3% & Irish 11% etc).

I'm not saying I doubt you, just curious how it came about without a significant Russian population.

Comment: @Pelinore admittedly I'm basing that on a cruise I took up the Alaskan coastline to Prince William Sound, where many of the stops had authentic Russian Orthodox churches, and in one case Russian was being openly spoken as a language. Tourist trap? Perhaps, but from what I saw (perhaps not a full sample set) there was still quite a bit of Russian heritage in play there.

Answer (score 6):

- Puerto Rico.
- District of Columbia.
- Cuba.
- [Panama](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/108546/2113).
- [Jefferson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_(proposed_Pacific_state)) splits from California and Oregon.
- New York City splits from [New York](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_and_secession_in_New_York).

It may be worth noting that you could get two of those if you wanted by not purchasing Alaska from Russia.  So Alaska might be part of Canada in your world, and the United States focused on the Caribbean area over the Pacific.  At an extreme, this might impact Hawaii as well, allowing Puerto Rico, Cuba, and Panama to replace Alaska and Hawaii.

Hawaii became a territory of the US as part of the [Spanish-American War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish%E2%80%93American_War).  But that war was based on the explosion of the USS Maine.  If the Maine had not exploded, it would have been harder to get the US involved in that war.  No war; no Hawaii.  This could also have led to Cuban separatists requesting statehood to bring the US into a war either then or later.  Perhaps a secession during the [Spanish Civil War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_Civil_War).  Or if Spain had taken sides in World War I.

Another state that might not be split would be West Virginia.  It split during the Civil War.  If you change the Civil War, it might not have split.  For example, if Virginia had voted to stay in the Union.  That would have had other ripple effects, as Robert E. Lee and a number of other officers and soldiers would have switched as well.

Vermont split off from New York.

Maine split off from Massachusetts.  This was part of the compromise to allow Missouri into the Union.  What if they had refused to compromise then?  The Civil War might have happened forty years earlier, avoiding a whole series of compromises that lead up to it.  Perhaps the South would have left the Union but rejoined fifty years later after international pressure caused it to end slavery.  This could have led to an entirely different set of states.  Also consider the potential impact on the [Mexican-American War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mexican%E2%80%93American_War).

As you've noted, Puerto Rico is the obvious choice.  One could easily see Cuba joining it and Alaska dropping out.

The District of Columbia is another obvious choice.  Instead of giving it three electoral college votes as a non-state, just give it statehood.

Panama is similar to Alaska as a choice.  It had a vital service that the US wanted to control (the Panama Canal).  Perhaps Teddy Roosevelt was not shot and roared his way to a third term.

Jefferson and New York City are perpetual gadfly options.  They are useful if you want something low impact and modern rather than something based on historical changes.

Comment: IIRC, under the treaty by which Texas joined the US, it's allowed to divide itself into as many as 5 states.  There's currently some interest (besides Jefferson) in dividing California into multiple states.  I'm sure upstate New York would like to get rid of NYC (though the preferred option is not statehood, but floating it out to sea and sinking it :-).  Nevada would be much happier without Clark County (Las Vegas ares), and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Lower Canada. George Washington was in the campaign that took it from the French for Britain. Later, in the revolutionary war in the alternate history he took it from the British as a 14th original colony.

The impacts would be immediate and dramatic,  as the fledgling USA would suddenly have a french speaking majority. the whole fur trade economy, and double the land that it had in real history.

**Edit: To explain why this results in 51 states**

If we started with 14, and much of history unfolded in a similar vein we'd be at 51 today, but we might speak french and have more of a code law system.

Comment: Where do you get a French speaking majority from? There were ~6 million colonists in the 13 colonies; there weren't nearly so many French in Canada, Louisiana, or indeed in the whole world outside of France, at that time. -1.

Comment: Ah well I got suckered in by the urban legend that German (or Dutch in some versions) missed begin the official language of the united states by 1 vote, and saw the addition of french as a contender as an opportunity.  The truth is that the USA did not have an "official language" until 2006, with the vote split largely along party lines.

Answer (score 3):

In 2003, a poll of Taiwan Students between ages 13-22 found that 55% supported US statehood while 38% favored becoming a province of China.  In 2008, a political organization in Taiwan was founded on the basis that they believe Taiwan and some surrounding Islands are already territories of the United States.  Perhaps an alternate history where Main Land China was more aggressive to Democracies forces Taiwan to petition for statehood for protection.

Comment: I like this a lot.  It is unexpected but plausible.

Answer (score 2):

I would consider the most likely 51st states to be those that would have formed earlier on, while state borders were not quite settled.

## [Little Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_Illinois)

Southern Illinois was settled before the northern part of the state. Many of the settlers came from Kentucky and Tennesssee, and there was a large Scots-Irish contingent. These regions were connected largely by water along the Mississippi and Ohio rivers to towns like Louisville, St. Louis, Memphis, and New Orleans; all in the south, or at least in slave states. Note that Cincinnati (not in the south) was not directly accessible by boat at this time, due to the Falls of the Ohio.

Northern Illinois was largely settled by Yankees. Many prominent early Chicago citizens were from New England and the rapidly expanding city was economically connected to New York City, first by lake navigation and the Erie Canal, and then by rail.

The cultural differences were such that there was significant pressure before the civil war for the state to be split in two. It was, after all, the second largest state in the Union when it joined (slightly smaller than Georgia). A split in, say around the time of the Compromise of 1850, wouldn't have been unexpected. For example, with Iowa, Wisconsin, and Minnesota joining between 1846 and 1858 as Free States, a compromise to allow Egypt to secede as a slave state might have made political sense. By the 1860s, many of the separatists had joined the Confederate armies (and then lost the war) so the pressure to secede dissipated.

## [Frankland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Franklin)

There was a quasi-independent state of Franklin that formed in the what is now Eastern Tennessee. North Carolina attempted to sell the counties to the Continental Congress to pay of Revolutionary War debts. Then Congress wasn't keen since it needed money, then North Carolina reneged. Eventually, a local delegation petitioned the Continental Congress for statehood, but only got 7 states to support them, less than the 2/3 majority required.

There was a bunch of maneuvering and rival governments set up, and a bunch of land was stolen from the Cherokee (of course) but eventually by 1789 the whole area ended up back under North Carolina control. The next year, North Carolina ceded the whole area of modern Tennessee to the Southwest Territory, and Tennessee became a state in 1796.

Tennessee is somewhat evenly divided into three subregions, an Appalachian region around the Knoxville, Chattanooga and Johnson City, a central region around Nashville, and a western region around Memphis, all with different cultural characteristics. Nashville has a lot in common with central Kentucky and the Bluegrass region, Memphis was part of King Cotton like the rest of the Mississippi Delta, and Appalachian Tennessee is, well, Appalachian. Its pretty reasonable for Tennessee to have ended up as at least two different states, not lead because Appalachian Tennessee did not have many slaveholders unlike the rest of the state. Scott County (which wasn't in the original Frankland, but is right next to it) [attempted to stay in the Union](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_of_Scott) in 1861.

## [Some parts of Texas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas_divisionism)

Texas was much, much larger than any other state when it joined. There have been many proposed divisions of Texas, that Wikipedia page doesn't really do the history justice. I assume it is because Texas, while extremely proud of their history, don't know how to use computers (hi JD).

## Colorado (not the current Colorado!) and Shasta (52 states!)

The Compromise of 1850 allowed California to come in as one Free State. This was because no on in California was excited about slavery, but the Slave states wouldn't allow for multiple free states tipping the balance in the Senate.

In 1855, the Calfornia Assembly passed a plan to split the state into three. Everything south of Monterrey and Merced counties would be come the state of Colorado, and 12 northern counties would become the state of Shasta (incidentally, roughly the same borders as the current state of [Jefferson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jefferson_(proposed_Pacific_state)) secession plans). This plan died in the state Senate.

A new try was made in 1859. The legislature passed and the governor signed the Pico Act, which split the southern counties off at the [36th parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/36th_parallel_north#/media/File:Southern_California.png). San Louis Obispo, Kern, San Bernardino, and counties south would have become the new state of Colorado. A referendum in these southern counties passed and the issue went to the federal Congress in 1860. Of course, by the time the issue got to DC, the Civil War was on its way, and the issue was never really revisited after the war.

Basically, had the timing of the Civil War been different, or had the 1855 resolution passed the way the 1859 one had, it is likely that California would be two or three states (and that modern Colorado would be named 'Jefferson'). This is the most likely 51st state, but it is just as likely to have been a 52nd state as well.

Answer (score 2):

**If the Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo went a different way, the United States could have a lot more than 51 states.**

[image: US Territorial Acquisitions]

Treaty of Guadalupe Hidalgo is the peace treaty signed by the United States and Mexico that ended the Mexican–American War (1846–1848). The treaty granted the United States the Mexican territory of Alta California, which eventually becomes the states of California, Nevada, Utah, Colorado, Arizona and New Mexico.

At the time, some people in the United States wanted the entire nation of Mexico. President Polk decided to keep Mexico as a viable Republic. The treaty could have easily included Baja California, Sonora, Chihuahua, Coahuila and what eventually became known as the Gadsden Purchase.

In your alternate history, you could include the Northern States of Mexico and perhaps have the disputes that occurred in the Oregon Territory be settled, so that Washington, Oregon and Idaho remained one state.

Good luck with your flag design of 51 stars.

Answer (score 1):

The USA never becomes independent in the way that history went.  Instead, reason prevailed on the English side and the colonies were not provoked to war. However, they continued on a similar path of growth, immigration and expansion.

Eventually, in the late 1800s, the economic, demographic and political center of gravity is such that the effective capital of the UK-USA becomes New York (Washington does not need to exist in this world).

This is, of course, a dramatically different timetable. If we add the UK and USA of 1900 together, we have a global superpower quite possibly capable of deterring the world wars.  The flag may have 51 stars, or it may not even exist.

Comment: [**The Solemn League and Covenant**](http://www.bethisad.com/maps.htm). Capital at Philadelphia, rather than New Castreleon, but similar results. (Details [*here*](http://ib.frath.net/w/North_American_League).)